# Browser Sync not reloading with gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to gulp browser sync as follows

```
var liveReload = require('browser-sync').create();

//reload when something changes once scss is converted to css
gulp.task('trigger-reload', ['sass'], function(){
    liveReload.reload();
});

//set watchers to reload
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    liveReload.init({
        server: {
            baseDir:'./'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['trigger-reload']); //js change
});
```

Now when I make changes to the js file I see the following on my terminal :

```
[00:19:23] Starting 'trigger-reload'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[00:19:23] Finished 'trigger-reload' after 282 μs
```

But it actually does not refresh the page, I have to manually refresh to see my changes. Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was doing a simple mistake:

We actually need to mention which file to reload as follows:

```
 liveReload.reload('./index.html');
```

That works!